# PHP login form redirect to offline, iPhone Web App

Tags: php, iphone, html, forms, hybrid

I have an offline html document with a login form.

It sends the information with POST to 'login.php' (which checks your username and password, and starts the session) on my server (online).

In that php file I have use this to 'redirect' to the page where you are logged in:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

So now it redirects to another php file on my server (index.php) , but it needs to redirect back to an offline HTML file (that is in that hybrid app `<<kind of web app but offline>>`) called index.html.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there are several issues with this approach.

First you have a fundamental security design flaw, since everyone could access those static offline pages directly, thus simply bypassing your login.

Second you have no means to directly access local content on the client side from the server. This would be a huge security gap in the client side browser, since it would allow any server to access local content without the knowledge of the user! This obviously only applies if you use a "normal" browser. Things are different if you implement an own http client / an own browser with its own logic. In that case you are free to do whatever you want. You could for example simply send a self defined header and react to it. But obviously implementing a custom browser not trivial, although certainly possible when you reuse existing components.

That said, you might want to give it a try if that really does not work with the standard browser on your phone. Since you use an iPhone I would never rely on any of the software in there to be secure. Note that in general you can use a redirection header not only with relative paths as you do, but also with absolute urls. So what happens if you just redirect to a file url?

```
header('Location: file://some/folder/file.static');
```